# vector subscript out of range when writing to file

Tags: c++, vector

I want to write a vector to a file, which represents the outcomes of a function that increments j with steps of "double Golf_dl".
The vector itself must have "int Golf_NL" elements in it. (Golf_dl is a private member of class Tsunami)
The problem is that I get a constant vector with all values equal to 0.5, which is rubbish.
Can someone see what's wrong?

Code:

```
void T_Tsunami::Toestand(int nl)
{
    struct pb
    {
        std::vector<double>& v_;  

        pb(std::vector<double>& v) 
        : v_(v){}; 

        pb& operator+(double i) 
        {
            v_.push_back(i);
            return *this;  
        }
    };

    for( double i = 0; i < nl; i++ )
    {   
        double j=0; 
        double y = 0.25*(1-tanh(double(j-75)/5));
        j+=Golf_dl;
        pb(T_1)+y; 
    }
}

void T_Tsunami::Write(vector<double>d)
{
        const int Naamgrootte=64; 
        char Naam[Naamgrootte];
        std::cout << "Geef een bestandsnaam in" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> Naam;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::ofstream outFile(Naam);
        if (!outFile)
        {
            std::cerr << "Kan bestand niet openen" << std::endl;
            exit (1);
        }

        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            outFile << d[i] << std::endl;
        }
        outFile.close();    
}
```

Comment: T_1 is also a private member (vector)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: `Can someone see what's wrong?`  So you want us to run the computer in our heads?  Have you used the debugger?

Comment: I've been trying to find out what's wrong with it for the last 3 hours now..

Comment: @user3600130 - and how have you tried to find this out? By just looking at your code? Well, that is not the most productive way to find bugs. Please learn to use the debugger that comes with your compiler. This is the way anyone on SO would find your error(s). If you did that, instead of 3 hours, it may have taken you just a few minutes to, at the very least, pinpoint what the issue is, if not outright fix the problem.

Comment: Well the compiler does build it, but the vector just gives values that are completely wrong.

Comment: @user3600130 Compiling is not debugging.  Just because a program compiles successfully does not mean it will run successfully.  I guess you really don't know what `debugging` means.  Moreover, you didn't post a complete, but small program demonstrating the problem.  Where is the main() program?

Comment: Change `for (int i = 0; i < 100` to `for (int i = 0; i < d.size()`

Comment: Also use `std::string` instead of `char Naam[...]`, this will avoid buffer overflows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in here:

```
for( double i = 0; i < nl; i++ )
{   
    double j=0; 
    double y = 0.25*(1-tanh(double(j-75)/5));
    j+=Golf_dl;
    pb(T_1)+y; 
}
```

Consider the fact that the loop variable, `i`, is not used anywhere inside the loop.  Also, `j` and `y` do not retain their values between loops (they are not `static`).

Comment: I guess he meant that `double j = 0;` comes before the loop

Comment: Ah, you gave it away! :)  I was trying to guide @user3600130 to find the problem on their own.

Comment: Got it, I changed that. Also the Write-funcion caused the vector to be too short. Thanks for helping me out, @PaulMcKenzie I will figure out how to debug now, always thought it was the same as compiling.